# использование хоткейев keyboard

Tags: python, клавиатура

у меня есть код

```
import keyboard

key = 'ctrl'
key2 = ' + c'

keyboard.add_hotkey((key + key2), lambda: keyboard.write('hello'))
```

когда я зажимаю alt + с выводит сhello, когда должно выводить просто hello, как сделать так чтоб при нажатии альт+с вводило только слово hello, без буквы с?

Comment: Собственно проверил Ваш код все ок работает. Единственное alt или ctrl все же?? при  ctrl+c может срабатывать KeyboardInterrupt от этого и лишняя ^C .попробуйте другую комбинацию.

Comment: извините, перепутал. я использовал альт. можете написать это как ответ, я отмечу его правильным, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код работает правильно. Единственное alt или ctrl?
При ctrl+c может срабатывать KeyboardInterrupt от этого и лишняя ^C . Попробуйте другую комбинацию.